# How to Make Fragment Completely Fill Screen Width (Apparent Margin when Using Fill_Parent)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to insert a fragment into my application and it's essentially a coloured bar with a few buttons on it. However, whenever I put the fragment onto the main xml file, there's always a bit of a white margin regardless of whatever I do. Here's an sample of some of the fragment code I have in my main xml:

```
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:name="sample"
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        tools:layout="@layout/sample"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />
```

Even though I set the margin to 0dp and the width to fill_parent, there's still a white margin/border on the outside. Is there any way to make a fragment fill the screen widthwise entirely? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the complete xml file?

Comment: what Apoorva said, I'm guessing the parent ViewGroup has a padding or margin defined in it.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. I had this inside my <RelativeLayout> in the main xml file:


    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >


It was fixed once I removed those. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @LucasCrawford By the way, I'd be happy to accept your answer but I can't accept it as a comment right now :)

Comment: @kathy added an answer :)

Comment: Haha great, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have padding and/or margin defined in your parent's ViewGroup that is causing the Fragment's extra spacing.  Check the Parent who contains the Fragment and remove the padding :)